# Why does accessing my classes field return null?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to better understand why when I access the 'user' field in my Game Master class in one way it returns null. But if I access it in a different way I get the value I want.

```
 class GameMaster
{
    public Player user;
  
    public Player User { get; set; }

    public GameMaster()
    {
        this.user = new Player(50);
        
    }
```

So then when I try and access the field object (user) in my gm object. One way returns null and the other returns the int 50 I wanted.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
   
        GameMaster gm = new GameMaster();
       
        Console.WriteLine($"You have ${gm.user.Funds} to play with"); // returns 50
        Console.WriteLine($"You have ${gm.User.Funds} to play with"); // returns null crashes program
    }
    }
```

I believe both would be valid ways to access the user field in my GM object. My thought is maybe it's how the property for my user field works. But I'd be immensely grateful  if someone could provide me an explanation of why one works and no the other.

Comment: `public Player User { get; set; }` This doesn't get magically associated with the other `user`. *You* have to do it.

Comment: You could say it does though with `private Player User;` so the confusion is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you expect to happen, will happen if you modify the code like this:

```
    public Player user;
  
    public Player User { get { return this.user; } set { this.user = value;} }
```

More explanation on `public Player User` can be found [on auto implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

> When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

```
public double TotalPurchases { get; set; }
```

So for your line `public Player User` the compiler will create the `private Player User;` variable.

So if you want to use the `user` member as a backing variable, I would suggest that you make it private and expose it as I show in the first example (no point accessing a member two ways, only grief lies this way).

Check encapsulation implementation for C# for more information. Extra hint: Always start by declaring your class members as private and expose more later as needed.

Comment: \So if I'm understanding correctly creating my get set
this way
`
public int Funds
        {
            get => funds;
            set => funds = value;
        }
 ` 
Functionally is different than auto property

`public int Funds { get; set; }`

Comment: No, it just creates the backing field automatically, so you don't have to do it.